# モーダル画面内の入力値が文字化けする(TOMCATによる文字化け）

Tags: angularjs, spring, tomcat, twitter-bootstrap

AngulerJSで入力があるモーダル画面を作成したのですが
Inputタグの入力値をサーバで受け取ると文字化けしています。
この場合文字セットをどこで指定すればよいのでしょうか？
（なお、モーダル画面用のスクリプトにはmetaタグにて文字セットを設定しています）

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="SeikyusakiInsert">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <div class="modal-header modal-dialog-header">
                    <h3>請求先一覧</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body modal-dialog-body-seikyusaki">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 control-label" for="InputCampanyName">会社名</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="CampanyName" id="CampanyName" ng-model="CampanyName"  placeholder="会社名" size="20" maxlength="60"  >
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                        <font coloer="red">${ErrCampanyName}</font>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 control-label" for="InputCampanyKanaName">会社カナ名</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="CampanyKana" id="CampanyKana" ng-model="CampanyKana" placeholder="会社カナ名" size="20" maxlength="60" >
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                        <font coloer="red">${ErrCampanyKana}</font>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 control-label" for="InputOrganization">組　織</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                            <select name="select_Soshiki" class="form-control" ng-value="valueSoshiki" ng-model="select_Soshiki" ng-options="Soshikimenu.CD_Code1 as Soshikimenu.CD_Name for Soshikimenu in SoshikiList ">
                            </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
                        <font coloer="red">${ErrOrganization}</font>
                </div>
                <br>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer modal-dialog-footer" >
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="modalSeikyusakiUpdate()">登録</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="$close()">閉じる</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</script>
```

Comment: Bootstrapのモーダルは親ページの一部として表示されますから、モーダル部分だけエンコーディングを指定することはできませんし、1サイト内で複数のエンコーディングを使うのはトラブルのもとになるので避けた方がいいです。で、親ページもutf-8だとしたら、あとはサーバー側の問題のような気がするのですが、モーダルでないフォームからは正常に送信できるのでしょうか？

Comment: 親画面からは通常に受け取れています。ちなみに、受け取る側はJavaでSpringフレームワークで受け取っています。この質問をした後に、$httpでUTF-8を指定してみましたが同じでした

Comment: 親画面の漢字入力はJava（SpringMVC）で受け取っていますが、問題なく受け取れます

Comment: 入力文字とサーバで受け取った際の文字化けの値（できればバイト列）を追記頂くことは可能ですか？どのように化けているかから原因を推測できないかなと考えています。

Answer (score 1):

色々と調べた結果Tomcat5.X以降においてGET時に日本語が文字化けするとのことでした
参照
http://ameblo.jp/spring-beginner/entry-10429339939.html
そこでサーバー側（私の場合、Eclipseのテスト用TOMCAT7）のserver.xmlの以下のパラメータに以下の項目を追加したら治りました。

```
<Connector acceptCount="100" connectionTimeout="20000" 
 disableUploadTimeout="true" enableLookups="false" 
 maxHttpHeaderSize="8192" maxSpareThreads="75" maxThreads="150" 
 minSpareThreads="25" port="8080" redirectPort="8443"
useBodyEncodingForURI="true"<==これを追加
 />
```

ただし、今回はモーダル画面からPOSTしているのでちょっと違いますが、ちなみに
POSTに関しては（親画面はPOSTの処理）web.xmlに対して以下のパラメータを入れてあります

```
<!-- 文字コード対応 -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>
        org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter
        </filter-class>
        <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```